# Infix to Postfix in python: why my programm is not able to pop the last element?

Tags: python-3.x, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

Here is my implementation to convert Infix expression to Postfix expression

```
from ArrayStack import ArrayStack

class Convertor:
    ''' Class to convert the Infix exp into Postfix exp'''

    def __init__(self,exp):
        ''' Constructor to initialize the class variable '''

        self.infix = exp
        self.stack = ArrayStack(len(exp))

    def is_operand(self,sym):
        ''' Check if symbol is operand '''

        return sym.isalpha()

    def precedence(self,sym):
        ''' Returns the precedence of the operator'''

        if sym == '+' or sym == '-':
            return 1
        elif sym == '*' or sym =='/':
            return 2
        elif sym == '^':
            return 3
        else:
            return -1

    def infix_to_postfix(self):
        ''' Converts the inifx exp into postfix exp '''

        postfix = []
        for i in self.infix:

            if self.is_operand(i):
                postfix.append(i)

            elif i == '(':
                self.stack.push(i)

            elif i == ')':
                 while(not self.stack.is_empty() and self.stack.top() !='('):
                        postfix.append(self.stack.pop())

                 self.stack.pop()
            else:
                while (not self.stack.is_empty() and self.precedence(i) <= self.precedence(self.stack.top())):
                    postfix.append(self.stack.pop())

                self.stack.push(i)

        while (not self.stack.is_empty):
            postfix.append(self.stack.pop())

        postfix.append(self.stack.pop()) # I don't know why an element still existing in the stack , can any one help
        print(postfix,len(postfix))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    exp = "a+b*(c^d-e)^(f+g*h)-i"
    print(exp,len(exp))
    convertor = Convertor(exp)
    convertor.infix_to_postfix()
```

I am not getting why my program is not able to pop the last element in the stack. I am doing it after the completion of the loop (look at the comment : line 55)

Please visit my github repo in needed :[github repo](https://github.com/SriNandan33/Py-DS-n-AlGO/tree/master/Stack)